# How to create mutation apollo server express 2.7.0?

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js

How to create mutation in apollo server express?

```
Mutation:{
    changeStatusPedido: async (obj, args, context, info) =>
                                    db.evento.update(
                                         { estado_pedido: args.estado_pedido },
                                              { where:
                                                 { id_evento: args.id_evento }  
                                     }),     
 },
```

log:

> Executing (default): UPDATE `evento` SET `estado_pedido`=? WHERE `id_evento` = ?

graphql result:

```
"errors": [
{
  "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Evento.id_evento.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 3,
      "column": 5
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "changeStatusPedido",
    "id_evento"
  ],
```

Comment: mutation probably should return some data/object as defined in mutation query

Comment: Your resolver should return an `Evento` object, but that's not what `db.evento.update` returns. See the linked post for details.